# A separable, regular space which has cardinality of the continuum but is not first countable?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Actually the title says it all. Is there such a topological space which is separable, regular, has cardinality of the continuum but is not first countable?

If so, is there also an example of a topological vector space having this property?
Thank you!

Comment: Well, according to [Spacebook](http://austinmohr.com/?page_id=146), Steen and Seebach don't know of one.

Comment: Yes, they show only some with cardinality power set of continuum or countable ones...

Answer (score 4):

Let $D=\{p_\xi:\xi<2^\omega\}$ be a family of $2^\omega$ free ultrafilters on $\omega$. The space $X=\omega\cup D$; clearly $|X|=2^\omega$. Points of $\omega$ are isolated, and for each $\xi<2^\omega$ the family $$\mathscr{B}_\xi=\big\{\{p_\xi\}\cup U:U\in p_\xi\big\}$$ is a local base at $p_\xi$. Then

$$\big\{\{n\}:n\in\omega\big\}\cup\bigcup_{\xi<2^\omega}\mathscr{B}_\xi$$

is a clopen base for $X$, which is clearly $T_1$, so $X$ is Tikhonov (and hence certainly $T_3$). $X$ is separable, since $\omega$ is dense in $X$. Finally, $X$ is not first countable at any point of $D$.

Comment: Thank you! This is an answer!

Comment: @Aljosa: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

> **Example**: Let $X=\mathbb R^{s}$, where $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology and $\omega<  s < \mathfrak c$. There is a [result from Pondiczery, Hewitt and Marczewski](http://planetmath.org/hewittmarczewskipondiczerytheorem)
>
> **If there are not more than $\mathfrak{c}$ ( which is the continuum), separable topological spaces, then their product is still separable.**

It is easily to see that $X$ is regular, separable, however it is not first countable.

Comment: You shouldn't use $\frak s$. since $\frak s$ denotes the splitting number (a cardinal characteristic of the continuum), whereas the link to PlanetMath suggests this is true for every cardinality between $\omega$ and the continuum (assuming that one exists to begin with, of course).

Comment: I think the proof is simple enough to cite: we can assume that $s\subseteq {\bf R}$; the countable dense subset is the ${\bf Q}$-linear span of characteristic functions of open intervals with rational endpoints intersected with $s$.

Comment: This leaves open the question of whether one can find a counterexample assuming CH.